# How to place multiple cvt windows at different positions on a screen

Tags: opencv

Is there a way we can position different cvt windows at specific positions?

My code displays different types of images at different points in the code, which means I have multiple `cv2.imshow(xxx,yyy)`'s.
When I use `moveWindow("firstWindow", 20,20)`, I'm able to position it properly.

But, when I'm using `moveWindow('secondWindow', 200, 200)` or for third window, it's not working.
How do we position each window at specific positions?